# Using zlib with C

Tags: c, zlib

I am currently learning C, and am having some issues with trying to make a small program that utilizes zlib.

I have managed to compile my application (using Codeblocks/MinGW) with the zlib libraries, and compilation works fine. I have used an example based upon the [zpipe.c](http://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c) example found over at the official zlib site (zlib.net).

On execution, the output zip file is created, but it seems malformed and/or empty. I am unable to open it using 7zip.

Here is the code that I have modified. I have simply replaced the main() function within zpipe.c.

```
int main() {
    printf("Compression test...");

    int ret;
    FILE *fpsource;
    FILE *fpdest;

    fpsource = fopen("test.txt", "rb");
    fpdest = fopen("output.zip", "wb");

    ret = def(fpsource, fpdest, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
    if (ret != Z_OK) {
        printf("failure\n");
        zerr(ret);
    }
    else {
        printf("success..\n");
    }

    fclose(fpsource);
    fclose(fpdest);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I receive no errors, and my 'success' message is printed. It's just the output file is corrupt.

Comment: what does 7zip say when opening the file?

Comment: @H2CO3, on POSIX, `EXIT_SUCCESS` is defined as `0` AFAIK, but it could be some other value too...

Comment: @CharlesB Just a generic "Cannot open file 'output.zip' as archive."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

zpipe.c as-is will generate the zlib format, which is raw deflate data wrapped in a zlib header and trailer.  7zip won't recognize that.  It will recognize the gzip or zip format, which are entirely different wrappers on the same raw deflate data.

You can modify zpipe.c to use deflateInit2 (and inflateInit2) instead of the versions without the "2" to select the gzip format instead of the zlib format.  You can read [zlib.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h) for how to do this.

Comment: An answer from one of the author of zlib !

Answer (score 4):

The code discussed simply compresses the file using the DEFLATE algorithm. The appropriate structures that make it a zip or gzip file are missing.